# Where to download org.apache.java.lang package?

Tags: java

I want to use org.apache.java.lang.Bytes class in my code. For that, i need org.apache.java package. Is it a free source package and Where shall i download?

Answer (score 3):

Its already deprecated! http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/java/lang/Bytes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of jar files containing this class [here](http://findjar.com/class/org/apache/java/lang/Bytes.html).

I think [findjar.com](http://findjar.com) is generally a nice tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sonatype public repository](http://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;classname~org.apache.java.lang.Bytes) to search for jars by classname.

The search shows it is freely available on the [Maven central repository](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/turbine/turbine/2.3.2/) or the Turbine [download page](http://turbine.apache.org/download.html) under the [Apache License](http://turbine.apache.org/common/license.html), though it was removed in the 2.3.2 release as it had previously been deprecated in favour of using Jakarta Commons.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer from @Daff (btw, thanks that is what I was looking for):

For newbies like me, once you get that .jar file, you need to add it to your JDK/JRE's ext folder. e.g.:
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0\lib\ext
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\ext\

See: [https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/background/13files_and_directories/86packages-installing.html](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ediam/java/online/notes-java/background/13files_and_directories/86packages-installing.html)

** This is a really old blog, but the info is nonetheless useful.